# Print to the console using in-place command-line editing

Tags: ruby, console

When using `ruby -pi.xxx -e '$stdout.print $_' ./some_file.txt` ruby is going to write into the file `some_file.txt` and I will end up having every text line twice in my file.

How can I redirect the input to end up in the console and not in my file?

Comment: What does `-pi.xxx` mean ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit -p prints, -i.xxx uses .xxx extension for a back up file

Comment: remove `$stdout.print` it is duplicating what `-p` does

Comment: @bjhaid I never have seen this, any handy resource do you have ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit man ruby, it is all in the man pages, when you want to use ruby like a unix command the man page is the best place to look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Ruby man page:

> **-i extension**
>
> Specifies in-place-edit mode.  The extension, if specified, is added to old file name
>       to make a backup copy.

In-place edit mode means that the output of the program is written to the original file instead of $stdout. To change this back to printing to stdout, simply leave out the `-i` flag, i.e.

```
ruby -pe '$stdout.print $_' ./some_file.txt
```

Some side notes:

- `$stdout.print $_` does exactly the same as `print $_`
- I hope your example is not actual code, because it doesn't make very clear what it is supposed to achieve. To double the lines in a file I would rather write either `ruby -ne 'puts $_ * 2' ./some_file.txt` or `ruby -pe '$_ *= 2' ./some_file.txt` although I think the first one is clearer.